# How to broadcast a message within the same JVM process with Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I am consuming a directory and I would like to broadcast a message to listeners within the same JVM process. I don't know who the interested parties are because they register themselves when they come up: the set of services within my JVM process depends on configuration.

Multicast does not seem to be what I want because I don't know at route build time where to send messages.

Besides using a queuing solution (ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ), are there other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Camel SEDA component can give you this. However, it's only valid inside of the current Camel context. If that restriction works for you it's the way to go. It'll handle both a queue style messaging system or pub/sub.

[Camel SEDA Component](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? SEDA with `multipleConsumers=true` is exactly what I need.

Comment: I *want* the same message to be sent to all consumers. I want to reproduce what would be a Fanout exchange in RabbitMQ / AMQP.

Comment: @boday "each message will only be processed once" is wrong, see the example in my answer.

Comment: In contrast to `SEDA`, `VM` allows the communication between routes in different Camel routes

Comment: I stand corrected, there is a pub/sub mode for SEDA, but it does require you defining multiple routes...recipientList seems cleaner  for dynamic sending of the same message to multiple recipients...

Answer (score 1):

use the [recipient list](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) pattern as it resolves the destination endpoints at runtime...

for example, you could implement a method to dynamically determine the recipients, etc...

```
from("direct:test").recipientList().method(MessageRouter.class, "routeTo");

public class MessageRouter {
    public String[] routeTo() {
        return new String[] {
            "direct:a", "direct:b"      
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case, the recipient list would have to be known globally somewhere so I can add it per-message. I really wanted something similar to a queue with pub-sub semantics.

Comment: -1 The question was to show alternatives to queuing solutions (ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ).

Comment: this doesn't require AMQ, was just in the example destination (which I removed for clarity)

Answer (score 1):

Beside the queuing solutions (JMS/ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ), you could use the [VM](http://camel.apache.org/vm) component for intra JVM communication. VM is an extension of the [SEDA](http://camel.apache.org/seda) component. In contrast to `SEDA` that can only be used for communication between different routes in a single Camel context, `VM` can be used for communication between routes running in different contexts.

Sending a message:

```
final ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
template.sendBody("vm:start", "World!");
```

With `multipleConsumers=true` it is possible to simulate Publish-Subscribe messaging, i.e. it is possible to configure more than one consumer:

```
from("vm:start?multipleConsumers=true")
     .log("********** Hello: 1 ************");
from("vm:start?multipleConsumers=true")
    .log("********** Hello: 2 ************");
```

This prints:

```
route1 INFO  ********** Hello: 1 ************
route2 INFO  ********** Hello: 2 ************
```

However, in contrast to JMS/ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ, the messages can not leave the JVM. And the messages are not persisted. That means that the messages are lost, a) if no consumer has been started when the message is sent, b) if the JVM crashes before the messages are consumed.

Comment: I stand corrected as I was not aware of that option/mode...general use is as a BlockingQueue using concurrentConsumers, etc..